# Adding extra fields to Laravel Spark Teams

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

Building out a project in Laravel Spark and need to add a couple of extra fields to the Teams.

I am offering a free trial, the fields on the registration page are the usual user fields and also the team name. I need to also add a 'branch_name' and 'contact_email' for the teams on registration.

I have modified my view to have these fields, added the fields to my app.js:

```
Spark.forms.register = {
    team_branch: '',
    contact_email: ''
};
```

In my booted method in Spark Service Provider I have added:

```
Spark::validateUsersWith(function () {
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'vat_id' => 'max:50|vat_id',
        'terms' => 'required|accepted',
        'branch_name' => 'required',
        'contact_number' => 'required',
        'team_email' => 'required'
    ];
});

Spark::swap('TeamRepository@create', function($user, array $data)
{
    $attributes = [
        'owner_id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'branch_name' => $data['branch_name'],
        'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::teamTrialDays()),
    ];

    return Spark::team()->forceCreate($attributes);
});
```

The API response is validating the extra fields correctly, but the $data array passed into the create method of the TeamRepository doesn't contain the extra fields.

I cannot make the link of where to go next to get the extra fields being passed into that method.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.